# roslocate info in ROS groovy

Tags: ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I've been using ROS Fuerte since a few months.
Recently I've installed ROS Groovy to see what's new. Installation was no problem on my Ubuntu 12.10 system. However, I can not use 'roslocate info' for installing packages.
I usually installed stage, teleop_twist_keyboard, etc., with this method:
roslocate info stage | rosws merge - (then source setup.bash, and call rosws update).

Output on my system:

rope@computer:$ roslocate info stage

rosinstall malformed for package stage

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54024/roslocate-info-in-ros-groovy/) by [Peter Roos](https://answers.ros.org/users/2915/peter-roos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 119 on 2013-02-01

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, **roslocate** is not working very well at the moment. I believe this is a [known problem](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/issues/366), so please verify before opening another defect ticket.

EDIT: The source link on the [stage wiki page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/stage) suggests adding it to your workspace like this:

```
$ rosws set stage --svn https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/stage/trunk/
$ rosws update stage
```

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Peter Roos](https://answers.ros.org/users/2915/peter-roos/) on 2013-02-03**:
Well then, how do I install a package in ROS Groovy?